# Adding a type-safe timeout to async functions in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, types, promise

Today I was assigned to make a bunch of async functions in our repo time out if they take >2 seconds. Took this as an opportunity to try and learn more about typescript by making a generic function that would take our existing functions and "timer-ify" them, and return the correct type. Here's a version of what I came up with that works in a playground:

```js
type AsyncFn<T> = (...args: any[]) => Promise<T>

class MyClass {
    TIMEOUT = 2 * 1000

    fakePromiseFn(input: string): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // async stuff
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(input)
                resolve(input)
            }, 1000)
        })
    }

    async timedPromiseFn(input: string): Promise<string> {
        // why is result unknown
        const result = await this.time(this.fakePromiseFn.bind(this), input)
        return result
    }

    time<T>(fn: AsyncFn<T>, ...args: any[]): Promise<T> {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('timeout')), this.TIMEOUT)
        try {
            const results = await fn(...args)
            resolve(results)
        } catch(err) {
            reject(err)
        } finally {
            clearTimeout(timer)
        }
    })
  }
}

const myClass = new MyClass()
```

What I can't figure out is why is `result` in my `timedPromiseFn` type unknown? The return time of fakePromiseFn is `Promise<string>`, and in my `time` function, the promise is resolved with the result of calling whatever `AsyncFn` is passed in, and the return type of `AsyncFn` is T. I'm only using one T throughout, so why can't the compiler infer the correct type? What did I do wrong?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ytWC8KAA)

(in the playground link it seems to get the type right because I `return result` and it sees that the return type of `timedPromiseFn` is supposed to be `Promise<string>` so it just assigns that type to `result`. But if you don't return `result` it says unknown.

Comment: I see no issue in the playground. `result` is correctly type as `string`.  Which TS version are you compiling with ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler ah I think I was getting that problem in my actual project because I hadn't turned on strictBindCallApply.